# Resque & Redis: How to auto start servers in local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Currently while in dev mode, I have to run `redis-server` to start redis, and then `TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES='*' rake resque:work` to start resque. Then I can launch `rails s`

How can I make this happen automatically so that I only need to run `rails s` ? I've looked around but can only find good ways to do this in production.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Can easily do this using [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).